# Yii url manager rules for certain terms

Tags: yii, yii-url-manager

I need a rule to redirect only certain terms.

```
  '<view:(about)>'=>'site/page/view/<view>',
  '<view:(faq)>'=>'site/page/view/<view>',
  '<view:(terms)>'=>'site/page/view/<view>',
```

I cannot use

```
<view:\w+>'=>'site/page/view/<view>
```

because i am using another rule for all terms other than this.

So is there any way to write an expression to short the 3 line of code to single one like this.

```
<view:(about),(faq),(terms)>'=>'site/page/view/<view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<view:(about|faq|terms)>
```